# Equally spaced surface flaws

Tags: creality-ender-3, surface

I'm having an odd effect in my prints. There is some sort of surface problem that seems to be evenly spaced in z. I tried to tighten my belts, the print speed is 75 mm/s using a 32 bit board, on an Ender 3 Pro.

Any recommendations?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The surface defects you describe is caused by Z-wobble. Basically this leads back in a defect in the Z axis gantry where X and/or Y movements are transferred into the print head. This can be cause by:

- a damaged nut,
- lead screw not straight,
- stick-slip,
- binding,
- lead screw out of alignment with the coupler,
- lead screw touching the stepper shaft in the coupler,
- the Z guide (at the other side of the X-axis arm; the one without the extruder mounted on it) has too much friction of the wheels on the profile,
- play on the carriage,
- lead screw should be the same distance from the extrusion profile from top to bottom,
- etc.

Comment: ...and possibly a cummulative rounding error

Comment: @Trish Didn't you write a previous answer on that? Please add an answer or link to it.

Comment: It was discussed in https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10986/how-to-calculate-the-proper-layer-height-multiples